# finding total size of C files in gcc

Tags: bash, gcc, code-size

I'm trying to compute the *source code size* of `gcc` by considering `cpp` files first:

```bash
# NOTE: the cpp loop finishes immediately
LOC=0
BYTES=0
FILES=$(find . -name "*.cpp")
for f in ${FILES};
do
    BYTES_TAG=$(stat --printf="%d" $f)
    LOC_TAG=$(cat $f | wc -l)
    BYTES=$((BYTES+BYTES_TAG))
    LOC=$((LOC+LOC_TAG))
done
echo "LOC = $LOC, SIZE = $BYTES"
```

Then I try to sum the `*.c` files, but the bash loop *doesn't stop*. here is my `gcc` version:

```
$ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-11.2.0/gcc-11.2.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xf gcc-11.2.0.tar.gz
```

This is weird because counting *all* the files is immediate with:

```
$ find . -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: Add debug prints to your loop.

Comment: Or perhaps try `find . -name "*.cpp" -exec cat \{} \; | wc -lb`.

Comment: in your loop you're reading the whole content of all files. `find . -type f | wc -l` doesn't do it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I get an error with your suggestion: `find: ‘cat’ terminated by signal 13`.

Comment: I added debug prints for the `C` files finder (note that the `CPP` finder finished immediately). I see sizes running on the screen which seems to be making sense ... any idea how to continue?

Comment: You know there are existing tools that do this? Such as `cloc`?

Comment: Sorry bad argument to `wc`. Should have been `-lc` not `-lb`. To be absolutely sure, `wc --lines --bytes`.

Comment: You said "the bash loop doesn't stop". How did you know that it doesn't stop?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no I didn't know that ! maybe it's worth posting as an answer to get more attention for future readers, no?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. you're right, I assumed the time proportion to be roughly the same as the `CPP` case ... so after a minute or two I assumed something is wrong

Comment: *"maybe it's worth posting as an answer"* There are existing questions & answers about it, like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288409/395855

Comment: Soooo why not just add `echo $f` to the loop to see what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of all *.c and *.cpp files in bytes:

```
find . -name *.cpp -o -name *.c -exec wc -c {} \; | sed "s/ .*//" | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Number of lines in all *.c and *.cpp files:

```
find . -name *.cpp -o -name *.c -exec wc -l {} \; | sed "s/ .*//" | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Explanation: `find ... -exec` executes a command on all files it finds, replacing the `{}` in the `-exec` part with the file name(s). If you end the `-exec` part with `\;`, it will be executed once for each file. In some cases, ending the `-exec` part with `+` is more efficient -- this will execute for as many files as will fit in one command line.

`wc -l` and `wc -c` will print one line per file, with the number of lines / characters (bytes) followed by the file name. The `sed "s/ .*//"' will cut away everything after the number.

`paste -sd+` will then concatenate all the lines (`-s`) and separate them with plus signs (`-d+`). Piping this to `bc` makes `bc` execute the addition and give you the total you are looking for.

Meta answer: Learn about `find ... -exec`. Don't loop over `find` output, because you will get into trouble e.g. when file names contain spaces -- and `xargs` is in most cases unnecessary.

Comment: that's great ! each of the 3 options takes less than 5 seconds to finish !

Comment: last question: why does it output several `total`? When I run `find . -name "*.cc" -exec wc -l {} + | grep total` I get 5 `total`s

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Ah, bugger. Brainfart on my behalf. The `+` in there puts the files found on a single line for the `-exec`. If that line gets too long, `-exec` will execute multiple times. So you will have to exchange `+` with `\;`... which will not print a total at all. I am on my mobile ATM; will amend my answer with a "totalling" solution (piping the individual file's results to `bc`) ASAP.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom See reworked answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I try to sum the *.c files, but the bash loop doesn't stop

You just waited not enough time. Bash is a very slow programming language. For every single loop, your program `forks` a subshell and does `fork+exec` of  `stat`, `cat` and `wc`. And you are reading each file twice - once by `stat`, than by `cat`. That's a lot of processes and a lot of work and double the needed I/O.

Write the same code in AWK, Python or Perl or in C or in C++, it will be much faster.

> This is weird because counting all the files is immediate with:

The code you posted is counting the bytes of files *names*, not files content. To count bytes of files content, you would do `find ... | xargs wc ...` - pass *filenames* as arguments to `wc`.

Yes, a single pipeline of constant count of *two* processes *will be* a lot faster. Opening of files, counting bytes and lines, and the sum is calculated inside a *C program* `wc`, not by Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the TLDR answer based on @HolyBlackCat (see also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288409/counting-lines-of-code)):

- install `cloc` with `sudo apt install cloc`
- from the top level `gcc` directory simply run: `$ cloc .`
- Then just look at the relevant info (`C/CPP` for me):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Language  files          blank        comment         code
------------------------------------------------------------
C         45147         680546         889750        3465801
C++       27752         230223         289596        1097375
```